# Store in GeoServer sometimes doesn't show frames

Tags: geoserver

I have problem with my GeoServer, and specially with my created store, which should show on map some frames. Connection types are Oracle NG and Oracle Database, GeoServer version is 2.16.2. Store is connected to workspace where services are WMS and WFS. It disappears for some reason, and when I am logging to web GeoServer, going to store, and turning it off and on, frames shows again. And after a while again doesn't show on. GeoServer works fine, but with this store is a problem.

Is there any possibility, to reload this store somehow automatically once per day?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: You should probably try again with a supported version such as 2.21 or 2.22 - Oracle gets less love due to it's proprietary nature